# how to decode a hex string query from ether chain? web3.hexToString is not work

Tags: web3js, ether, web3j

`0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019b8af0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000220000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000026000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005c79a77000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000051bbd0e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002d47babd7afa34000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000313dbc6ed0900a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007c73b258cd46ecc90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023020033f77feefa7cb2b`

this is the source code. i tryed web.js and web3j to decode it, but not work.
even tryed decode to byte array and transfer the array to string. still not work.
please help. Thanks

the contract is: `https://moonscan.io/address/0x1337bedc9d22ecbe766df105c9623922a27963ec#code`

here is the source RPC request:
`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":22,"method":"eth_call","params":[{"data":"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","to":"0x1337bedc9d22ecbe766df105c9623922a27963ec"},"latest"]}`

Comment: Can you show the smart contract code that is encoding/saving this string? Can you show us the original string?
That payload doesn't seem to be a string but rather many different values encoded and you would need to know what values with what types are encoded there to be able to decode it.
Share more information to see if we can help.

Comment: If you want to know how strings are encoded and saved in storage and how to retrieve and decode them you can read here: https://coinsbench.com/solidity-layout-and-access-of-storage-variables-simply-explained-1ce964d7c738 in the section Strings and bytes

Comment: Alright it's not an etherscan contract, it's moonbeam but also copy from etherscan, here is the source RPC request, i think there are something regularity in this hex string that can indicates the type of values. @JeremyThen

Answer (score 0):

the first 4 bytes of data 0x252dba42 is method id that encoded by sha3 and sha3 is undecipherable. here is a way to find which method is '0x252dba42' represents actually based on database accumulated data：
`https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x99fbab88`